# Functions as Inputs in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, newtons-method

I am writing a function for **Newton's Method** in C++.
I want to be able to designate a function to be used in the algorithm, but I want it as an input.

For instance:

```
double newton(f,df,tolerance,initial_guess,max_iterations)
```

where **f** and **df** are the function and its **derivative** respectively.

But how do I do this?

Comment: You can do this e.g. using function pointers (pointer to functions).

Comment: Right, I recall reading something about them.  Could you give me some good reading material?

Comment: @RobinRobinovic in this particular case function pointers are very bad choice - they will be called in a loop - the overhead will be huge and compiler will not perform optimizations.  It is ok for learning purposes but not for performance critical cases

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using templates:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class F>
void foo(F f, double x) {
  printf("f(0) = %f\n", f(x));
}

int main() {
  foo(sinf, 0);
  foo(cosf, 0);
}
```

output:

```
f(0) = 0.000000
f(0) = 1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You would declare a function pointer as an input: here's a basic example:

```
void printNumber (int input) {
    cout << "number entered: " << input << endl;
}

void test (void (*func)(int), int input) {
    func(input);
}

int main (void) {
    test (printNumber, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The first parameter in test says: take a function named func, that has an int as input, and returns void. You would do the same thing with your function and its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative one, you can write as this in C++11.

(Modified from @Anycom's code, ^_^)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>


void foo(std::function<double(double)> fun, double x) {
  printf("f(0) = %f\n", fun(x));
}

int main() {
  foo(sinf, 0);
  foo(cosf, 0);
}
```